# Updating BMesh element indices

Tags: bmesh

I've noticed that after calling `bmesh.utils.edge_split` the new elements (vert, edge, loops) have -1 indices. They stay -1 even after calling `ensure_lookup_table()` for all elements.

But, after calling `bmesh.utils.edge_split` a second time, the elements from the first call now have valid indices, and only the new elements from the second call have -1 indices.

Is there a call I can make to ensure all elements have valid indices when I need them?

I'm currently doing this, but it seems ugly, and it's not obvious to me if this is allowed or not:

```
for vert_i, vert in enumerate(bm.verts):
    vert.index = vert_i
for edge_i, edge in enumerate(bm.edges):
    edge.index = edge_i
for face_i, face in enumerate(bm.faces):
    face.index = face_i
```

Comment: that looks like a bug, imho... maybe someone here will know about that